# C# WinForms .Net devexpress map Pin

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I work with Windows Forms in c#.I use Devexpress components in my project.I want join pins way different color.I add 2 group pins to map.First group pins way color red another group pins way color dark blue.Please help me.How i can solve this problem ?

[Please follow this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcvUP.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Source:** [Can I use different color for MapPushpins or is there just the orange one?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q377013)

> I regret to inform you that MapPushpins have only the default orange
>   color.
>
> As a workaround, you can assign an image with a desired pushpin color
>   to the map pushpin via the MapPointer.Image property.
>
> An alternative way is to specify different highlighted colors for an
>   image using the MapCustomElement.Fill, MapCustomElement.StrokeWidth
>   and MapCustomElement.Stroke properties.

**References:**
[Custom Route Colors](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q565809) -- See attached sample
[MapControl - changing colour of pushpins](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T146227)
[Map Control custom example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q568669)